# Count all the time the same value appears with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Welcome to another day, another SQL question.

I'm trying to list all the time, a value appears for all users.

I did something like that :

```sql
$nRows = $pdo->query('SELECT choix1, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix1')->fetchAll();
```

[List of choice from users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5wCa.png)

[List of city and available jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Z7v.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnGoD.png)

What I need is to be able to get the number of time a city was selected, not only from choice 1, then choice 2 ... but from all choice at the same time.

That number will be divided by the number of jobs available to get a "ratio" that tells how much a city is desired (I know, that the city and jobs are on the same col, but I failed exporting my csv, but it's another problem, I will start by entering the number of job by hand).

```php
$nRows = $pdo->query('SELECT choix1, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix1')->fetchAll(); 
$nRows2 = $pdo->query('SELECT choix2, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix2')->fetchAll(); 
$nRows3 = $pdo->query('SELECT choix3, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix3')->fetchAll(); 
$nRows4 = $pdo->query('SELECT choix4, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix4')->fetchAll(); 
$nRows5 = $pdo->query('SELECT choix5, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix5')->fetchAll(); 
$nRows6 = $pdo->query('SELECT choix6, count(*) as newchoice from users GROUP BY choix6')->fetchAll(); 

foreach ($nRows as $nRow) {
    print_r($nRows);
    echo ("<br>");
    $vchoix1=$nRow[1] / 4;
    echo ("<br>");
    echo($vchoix1);
}
```

This is my actual crappy code.

Thanks for reading. Have a nice day.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: If a city is in two choices in the same row, does that add 1 or 2 to the count?

Comment: Hello ! thanks for the precision, i'm using MySQL. 
Yes i need to list all the time a city appears, regardless of the choice number. Everytime it appears, i need to +1 my count.
I forgot to tell that users can't have 2 time the same choice, if they pick a city in choice 1, they can't pick the same city in choice 2 for exemple.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? MySQL 5.x is significantly different from MySQL 8.

Comment: 8.0.27 - MySQL Community Server from what i read on myphpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Union to turn the many horizontal columns into a single column:

```sql
select choix, count(*)
from (
    select choix1 choix from users
    union all
    select choix2 from users
    union all
    select choix3 from users
    union all
    select choix4 from users
    union all
    select choix5 from users
    union all
    select choix6 from users
) u
group by choix
```

Comment: Thanks ! the query seems to work ! what is the little "u" you wrote ?

Comment: @tontongako it's a table *alias* - it names the result of a subquery, in this case "u" (for "Union", but you could put any name there). It is required by most databases; if you omit it you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to do the same things. First of all, use object-oriented programming and not  procedural. , i think i could have been a lot lot faster.

With the help of Bohemian, he gave me the query to retrieve all choice.

the complete code to retrieve all choices and divide it by the number of jobs available is :

```php
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "pdo.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
}
$poste = $pdo->query('SELECT ville,poste from postes')->fetchAll(); 
$nRows = $pdo->query('select choix, count(*)
from (
    select choix1 choix from users
    union all
    select choix2 from users
    union all
    select choix3 from users
    union all
    select choix4 from users
    union all
    select choix5 from users
    union all
    select choix6 from users
) u
group by choix')->fetchAll();
$villes = $pdo->query('SELECT ville from postes')->fetchAll(); 
$resultat = array();
echo "<table>";
    echo"<td>";
foreach ($villes as $ville) {
    $qryville = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE \"$ville[ville]\" in (choix1,choix2,choix3,choix4,choix5,choix6)")->fetch();
$qryposte = $pdo->query("SELECT poste FROM postes WHERE ville = \"$ville[ville]\" ")->fetch();
if($qryville[0]==0){
    $resultat[$ville[0]] = 0;
}
else{
$resultat[$ville[0]] = ($qryposte[0] / $qryville[0]);
}
if ($resultat[$ville[0]] <= 0.30){
    echo "<br><p style=\"color: green;\"> Ville verte $ville[0] </p><br>";
    echo "Ratio actuel&nbsp" . $resultat[$ville[0]];
    echo "<br>"; 
 
} elseif ($resultat[$ville[0]] <= 0.65){
    echo "<br><p style=\"color: red;\"> ville rouge $ville[0] </p><br>";
    echo "Ratio actuel&nbsp" . $resultat[$ville[0]]; 
    echo "<br>"; 
}else {
    echo "<br><b><p style=\"color: black;\"> ville noire  $ville[0] </p></b><br>";
   echo "Ratio actuel&nbsp" . $resultat[$ville[0]]; 
    echo "<br>"; 
 }  
    }
?>
```